# Could not find class 'org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister' on devices < Android M

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, simple-framework

My application uses org.simpleframework.xml to process xml content. This works perfectly well on devices using Android M and above, however on devices lower than Android M i run into the following error:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister'
```

I include the library as seen below in my gradle

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
   exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
   exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Any valuable inputs appreciated.

P.S.: I use Android Studio 2.1.2 with the latest gradle version.

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: No Proguard used.

Comment: Are you using any other obfuscation tool?

Comment: No i do not use any obfuscation.

Comment: When i lower my gradle to 2.0.0 and my build tools to 22.0.2, it does not create a problem. It seems to work then.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use multiDex?

If so, make sure your applcation class

extends Application  ==>   extends MultiDexApplication

My app was ok on 5.0 ↑

but crashed on 4.xx devices with

"NoClassDefFoundError: org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister"

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent all of yesterday looking for this solution.